# why my break statement inside IF is not working?

Tags: c, if-statement, break

This is my code I am trying to print the subarray of the given sum
why break statement inside if condition is not working, help me with solutions..

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int n,s,i,temp=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    scanf("%d",&s);
    int a[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=i;j<n;j++){
       temp=temp+a[j];
       if(temp==s){
         printf("%d %d\n",i+1,j+1);
         break;
       }
    }
    temp=0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'? Did you debug the code to see what is happening?

Comment: a `break;` statement exits the inner most loop.  But you have a nested loop so `break;` exits the inner one and the outer one continues.  Maybe do this `i=n; j=n; break;` and that will force both loops to exit.

Comment: if you indent your code carefully, it's easier to see the loops

Comment: OT: 1) single character variable names I.E. `a`, `n`, `s` are meaningless, even in the current context. 2)  when the user runs the code, all they see is a blinking cursor and no indication of what they are expected to do.  This is a very poor way to write code.  Suggest prompting the user, then validate the values entered by the user.

Answer (score 1):

The break statement in C programming has the following two usages:

1. It can be used to terminate a `case` in the `switch` statement.
2. If you are using nested loops, the break statement will stop the execution of the innermost loop and start executing the next line of code after the block.

In your case the `break` statement will only break your inner loop. See here:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int n,s,i,temp=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    scanf("%d",&s);
    int a[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
       for(int j=i;j<n;j++){                  //
           temp=temp+a[j];                    //
           if(temp==s){                       //this loop is breaked
               printf("%d %d\n",i+1,j+1);     //
               break;                         //
           }
        }
        temp=0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The other `for` loop still continues.

Answer (score 0):

In C, a `goto` statement and label are used to break nested loops, e.g.

```
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
            temp = temp + a[j];
            if (temp == s) {
                printf ("%d %d\n", i + 1, j + 1);
                goto done;
            }
        }
        temp = 0;
    }
    done:;
```

Your other option is to set a flag (e.g. `int breakboth = 0;`) and then set `breakboth = 1;` when a break of both loops are needed and check immediately after the inner loop `if (breakboth == 1) break;`

```
    int breakboth = 0;
    ...
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
            temp = temp + a[j];
            if (temp == s) {
                printf ("%d %d\n", i + 1, j + 1);
                breakboth = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (breakboth);
            break;
        temp = 0;
    }
```

Either is fine. In both cases, `temp` remains equal to `s` as the `temp = 0;` statement is avoided.

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable answers!

Comment: Glad it helped. You would also want to validate every input, e.g. `if (scanf("%d",&n) != 1) { fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr); return 1; }`. (you can't use any input function correctly unless you ***check the return*** `:)`